# Angular 2: Parsing JSON in constructor

Tags: json, angular

I am sending a json reponse from server in the following format:

```
{id: Int, name: String,  childJSON: String}
```

and willing to map it to

```
export class Student{
    constructor(public id: string,
                public name: string,
                public childJSON: ChildObject) {

    }

export class ChildObject {
       constructor(public class: number,
                    public age: number){}
```

on doing `response.json() as Student;` I am getting `{id:1, name: "sumit", childJSON: "{class: 5, age: 10}"` i.e. childJSON has string type instead of ChildObject type. Basically the string is not mapped to my child object. Is this the correct way to achieve it or i need to send child object from the server instead of just JSON String

Comment: should be `{id: Int, name: String,  childJSON: ChildObject }`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh. Noooooooo. Looks like you're confusing TypeScript with another language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "re-hydrate" the objects manually in the constructor and you can't use the "parameter property" shortcut to do that (the technique where you used `public` in the constructor to automatically convert constructor params into class properties).

Here's how I would do it:

```ts
export class Student{
  constructor(options: {
                id: string;
                name: string;
                childJSON: any;
              }) {
    // Now you have to instantiate the class properties one by one.
    this.id = options.id;
    this.name = options.name;
    this.childJSON = new ChildObject(options.childJSON);
  }
}
```

And then to instantiate:

```ts
const student = new Student(studentJson);
```

Or, if you're using an Observable to fetch the data:

```ts
this.http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(studentJson =>
  this.student = new Student(studentJson)
}
```

This solution is more flexible, as you can pass the original JSON object directly for instanciation. In your example, you had to write something like:

```ts
// NOT GOOD: You must pass each property individually, in the right order...
const student = new Student(studentJson.id, studentJson.name,...);
```

Comment: const student = new Student(studentJson);, I can't do this as I have recieve and send data using observables;

Comment: Thanks, I hope this works. But my actual scenario is much more tedious than mentioned in the question. Though it was an insightful way to know :)